# HTML Live Text Update

Tags: javascript, php, python, html

I have the following Website: https://neat.000webhostapp.com/

I have set some example values under `Exhaust 4 Temp.`, `Battery Level` etc. However, what I'm looking to do is to update these values real-time (using Python). If I could be given the HTML code, I'm sure I could figure out how to make this Python compatible.

If it's changing a file's content, which the page will be reading from, then I can make Python modify the file accordingly.

Of course, I could just refresh the page. However, I would like to **only** change these values, without refreshing the entire page every time...

I took a look at http://www.labbookpages.co.uk/web/realtime.html (Dynamic Text), but I didn't exactly understand what it stated about the `liveData` file. Should I create a new `liveData` file (no extension)? If so, what should be the content of the file etc.?

Comment: Read up javascript and ajax.

Comment: You will need to refresh the content with [ajax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) or with [websockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket)